# How to differentiate two links with the same content using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that contains two links with the same text "Add new item", but are targeting different URLs.

I created a javascript that uses jQuery library which references the link by its text. The code is:

```
var anchorElement = $("a:contains('Add new item')");
```

This is fine when I want to reference the first link. But, how do I reference the second one, being that they have the same text? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop through use this

```
$("a:contains('Add new item')").each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

You can also grab them by index

```
var first = $("a:contains('Add new item')").eq(0);
var second = $("a:contains('Add new item')").eq(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am very new to the jQuery, so could you just explain what would this method return? For example, what if I had three links? What would the code look like for that? Thank you so much.

Comment: The first method just loops through all matches $(this) being the current match in each iteration

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much! I'll mark your answer as correct as soon as stackoverflow let's me (I need to wait for 8 more minutes :) )

Comment: Or even just $("a:contains('Add new item')")[1];

Answer (score 0):

Try searching about [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) or by iterating over them with `each()` Function.